# snmptt: Did not find 'Result' in module

Tags: snmp

I am using Centreon (Nagios) on Centos 6.2 and was importing some MIBs to use snmp traps.
One MIB seems to make some problems.

When I try to use snmptranlsate (or send a trap for testing purpose) I always get:

```
Did not find 'Result' in module VoiceObjectsServer-MIB (/usr/share/snmp/mibs/VoiceObjectsServer-MIB.txt)
```

When I try to translate it the output is:

```
# snmptranslate -m VoiceObjectsServer-MIB .1.3.6.1.4.1.24140.1.2.5.4.3
Did not find 'Result' in module VoiceObjectsServer-MIB (/usr/share/snmp/mibs/VoiceObjectsServer-MIB.txt)
VoiceObjectsServer-MIB::serverReset
```

So it seems to get translated?
When I try to send a trap the message above is given and no trap is sent.

I placed the mib file under /usr/share/snmp/mibs and imported them properly to the Centreon Trap Database.

I even can find a field "Result" in the MIB-file. But still something must be wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Import in the MIB the 'Result' is a reference to another MIB, being exactly it is the same MIB. And the MIB does not contain Result so error is thrown.
Removing the reference from the MIB worked fine.